# Arquivo corrompido ao copiar de uma pasta para outra

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, área-de-transferência

Estou localizando e salvando os arquivos em um listbox1, da seguinte maneira:

```
procedure Localizar(DIR,ARQ: string; LIST: TStrings);
var
SR: TSearchRec;
begin
{Garante a barra no final do diretório}
if DIR[length(DIR)] <> '\' then
DIR := DIR + '\';

{Encontra os arquivos e diretórios segundo o definido em ARQ}
if FindFirst(DIR + ARQ, faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
repeat
if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
begin
LIST.Add(DIR + SR.Name); //Grava o arquivo/diretório encontrado num TStrings
Application.ProcessMessages; //Essa linha pode ser eliminada se executar a procedure numa outra thread
end
until FindNext(SR) <> 0;

{Busca os subdiretórios de DIR}
if FindFirst(DIR + '*.*', faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
repeat
if SR.Attr = faDirectory then
begin
if (SR.Name <> '.') and (SR.Name <> '..') then
begin
Localizar(DIR + SR.Name, ARQ, LIST); //Reinicia a busca no subdiretório encontrado
Application.ProcessMessages; //Essa linha pode ser eliminada se executar a procedure numa outra thread
end;
end;
until FindNext(SR) <> 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Localizar('C:\Usina_Comvap_ex', '*.dbf', ListBox1.Items);
end;
```

e apos localizar esse arquivo, gostaria de transfeli-los para outra pasta da seguinte maneira:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
Origem:string;
Destino:string;
i : Integer;
 begin
  for i := 0 to listbox1.items.Count-1 do
    begin
      Origem:=listbox1.items[1];
      Destino:='C:\Users\Guilherme\Desktop\shp\'+ExtractFileName(listbox1.items[i]);
      CopyFile(PChar(Origem), PChar(Destino), true);
    end;
 end;
```

ok, ele copia os arquivos mas ao tentar abrir, ele comrrompe os arquivos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Peguei seu código, e adicionei alguns `Begins` e `Ends` apenas para compilar, e funcionou perfeitamente para arquivos xls.

Na sua mensagem, você esta tentando abrir um arquivo de extensão `.dbf` pelo Excel, e o problema é esse. Tanto é que se você prosseguir com essa mensagem, provavelmente, o próprio Excel vai sugerir algumas adaptações, e vai conseguir abrir o arquivo perfeitamente.

PS.: Testei seu código com arquivos `.dbf` também.

Comment: discordo, no caminho de origem, consigo abrir o .dbf corretamente,

Comment: @GuilhermeLima, com o Excel ?

Comment: sim, ou liboffice

Comment: Pode compartilhar o arquivo ?